# how many grams of butter can be absorbed by 5 egg yolks?

Tags: eggs, butter

my 5 egg yolks absorbed 75grams of butter today. finished product felt like it can absorb more fat.

what's the maximum it can absorb?

anyone else experimented?

Comment: Define „absorb“ please? What did you create? My first thought is „hollandaise” and yes, that would be way more than 15g per yolk.

Comment: Absorb means there's no visible sign of butter, no smell of butter and no taste of butter in the mix.

Comment: Here's what I did. On lowest heat, I stirred butter and egg yolk slowly. After there was no visible sign of butter, it looked like pudding. I increased the heat (to make sure it was cooked properly, not sure if this step is necessary). As a result I made something that looked like scrambled eggs. Only salt, egg yolk and butter. It was the best egg I've ever eaten in my entire life.

Comment: Way more than 15g per yolk? So 50g per yolk would be ok?

Comment: A hollandaise (the epitome of a butter & yolk emulsion) is around 75 to 85 g per yolk. Just to give you an idea.

Answer (score 5):

There isn't too much of an upper limit that way. Yolks can emulsify a lot.

> A single yolk can emulsify a dozen cups of oil or more. What is critical is the ratio of oil to water: there must be enough of the continuous phase for the growing population of oil droplets to fit into. For every volume of oil added, the cook should provide about a third of that volume in the combination of yolks, lemon juice, vinegar, water, or some other water-based liquid

(from On Food and Cooking by Harold McGee).

At the same time, an emulsion made with many cups of oil (or butter) per yolk is not going to taste the same, have the same texture, or be as easy to make as one made with more standard ratios. So while you probably *could* make a sauce with as much butter as you like, there is no good reason why you *should* try it. If you pick a good recipe, you have a much higher chance of ending up with something enjoyable.

Comment: Thanks. Kind of a silly follow up question. After I cooked this, its volume seemed pretty low. Where did the 75g of butter go? It looked like it disappeared

Comment: There is no mechanism for it to disappear. You probably had an incorrect expectation of the final volume. Next time, you can measure the volume of the final product, I am certain it will still be noticeably more than the initial 15+75.

Comment: butter has a lot of water, as do yolks - some if it evaporates.